# VLOOKUP on computed cell values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I cannot have `VLOOKUP` to properly work if it has to match computed values.

Please see [**this example**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuFGX4zNyxsudG1SR2FiM0xGd3g0ODlnanZHQUNqTmc&usp=sharing):

In `test` sheet, row `1` tests data in `computed` sheet, where `B2` cell is the result of `=RIGHT(A1, 4)`.

**Value 1234 is not found**

Meanwhile, on row 2 of `test`, if 1234 is the hardcoded value of the cell — sheet `hardcoded` —

**Value is found**.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it enough for you to change your formula to `=value(RIGHT(A1,4))` ?

I'd say not a bug (Excel behaves the same way). Use of =RIGHT has automatically output as a string. If instead you had had =1233+1 you should not have had any problem.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Honestly I can't get why Excel & C. ignore case and type of data on 90% of cases and take care only when it's obvious you don't... Pretty nonsense to me! +1 and accepted